# Variable Class Name Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm creating a new object that takes a string and a class.  Let's say I have a class called "Quiz.java".  What works:

```
headerItem = new TreeFieldItem(new QuizMenuItem(key, Quiz.class));
```

My "value" String returns as "Quiz".  How do I make this work?

```
 private ArrayList<TreeFieldItem> getListItems() {

    ArrayList<TreeFieldItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<TreeFieldItem>(14);

    TreeFieldItem headerItem    = null;

    Map<String, String> map = getMenuItems(R.xml.xml_quiz_menu);

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();

        **headerItem = new TreeFieldItem(new QuizMenuItem(key, value.class));**
        arrayList.add(headerItem);

    }

    return arrayList;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Class.forName(String)`

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classforname.html

```
headerItem = new TreeFieldItem(new QuizMenuItem(key, Class.forName(value));
```

You'll need to make sure that the value string is the fully qualified name of the class (including the package).